# Include JavaScript based on ActiveDirectory Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a single page application and in the start page I've linked to the ActionResult "_ADMIN()"

```
@Html.Action("_ADMIN")
```

Depending on the user's group membership, this ActionResult returns either an EmptyResult or its view:

```
    public ActionResult _ADMIN()
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

Its view consists of this one line:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/admin")
```

This works but feels suboptimal. I could copy the start page and create seperate ones for non-admins and admins, but that would be even more suboptimal. I'm using MVC 4.

**What's a better way to include a bundle of JavaScript only if the current user is in a certain Active Directory group?**

Comment: If you move the "if" to the view them you probably don't need "else"

Comment: Gave me an error when I tried that .. let me check again..

Answer (score 2):

You can add scripts depending on roles. Like that :

```
if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/admin")  
}
```

And on your Action method you add attribute then the user will be automatically redirected to the login page if it does not have rights. You can add this attribute also on whole class.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would only show the link to admin users:

```
if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
{
   @Html.Action("_ADMIN")
}
```

Then, in the event a non-admin tried to access the action method, I would block the request at the action method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult _ADMIN()
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Looks like I misread Html.Action() as Html.ActionLink(). Not sure if my answer would still apply